# Trying to find a ship from an '80s cartoon

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, cartoon

I have had this image of a ship from a cartoon stuck in my head but I can't seem to find it. I can't remember much about the ship but it had a unique gimmick. When in flight, the bow section is folded down, When it lands the bow folds up and a ramp extends and a vehicle comes out. The bow section is almost as box like as in the picture, with large wings on the sides. From the top it would look like a 'T'.

Here are two images from a side view to sort of visualize what I mean.

In flight:

[image: Ship in flight]

Landed:

[image: Ship Landed]

It wasn't a Transformer, so it wasn't from shows like *Macron 1*, *Robotech/Macross*, *Saber Rider*, etc.

The main reason I remember this ship existing, is that I built a Lego set of it. The bow was a pain to make work properly, and the vehicle that would come out was a micromachine. I am also 99% certain it was an '80s cartoon, but could also be from the early '90s.

Unless I am suffering from the Mandela effect...

TIA

EDIT: It was a custom Lego set, there was no Lego-Show tie in sets at that point in time.

Comment: Did the Lego set exist *as a set* or was it something you built and designed yourself?

Comment: This sounded familiar to me as well; initially thought it might be something Ulysses 31, Battle of the Planets, Bravestar, Jayve and the Wheeled Warriors, or Galaxy Rangers, but couldn't find anything matching for those.
The bit with the raised bow reminds me of the Serenity from Firefly.

Comment: @Valorum No was not a set, was a one I built & designed from memory of the show (was a lot fresher back then). :)

Comment: Can you sketch the whole ship? Was it armed, how it moved, was powered?

Comment: Something like [White base](https://www.1999.co.jp/eng/10005596) ?

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi That is part of the problem, I can't remember much more than that. IIRC, the rear end was very blocky with large wings, and the nose looked similar to Ranger1 from galaxy Rangers.

I can say with certainty it was not any kind of Gundam. 80s South Africa had very limited access to cartoons. And they were mostly US ones.

Comment: Sounds a bit like _[X-bomber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Bomber)_ aka _Star Fleet_, but isn't a close enough match to warrant an answer, hence the comment.

Comment: Perhaps [any of these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dy3RTFFhSYs) ring a bell?

Comment: Thunderbird 2? https://thunderbirds.fandom.com/wiki/Thunderbird_2

Comment: @DaleM No not thunderbirds.

Comment: Is it shaped like a Griffon from SC? https://www.artstation.com/artwork/gBKom

Comment: @SQB Great Video with some classics. However your 1st comment was spot on. It IS the X-Bomber. This shows you how faded the memory was! :) It wasn't even an animation. :D While checking I found this: The exact moment that was stuck in my head https://youtu.be/l1mTuorJEyc?t=691 Yeah so it is a weapon not ramp... lol Thank you.

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi It was more like the Caracal from EVE Online. It was in fact the X-Bomber from Starfleet.

Comment: It reminds me a little of the ship from the Micronaut’s comic.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is the X-Bomber from *[Star Fleet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Bomber)*.

The exact moment that was stuck in my head (at [11:31](https://youtu.be/l1mTuorJEyc?t=691)):

And it is a weapon, not ramp... lol.
This shows you how faded the memory was! :) It wasn't even an animation. :D

Thank you [SQB](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259871/trying-to-find-a-ship-from-an-80s-cartoon?noredirect=1#comment715326_259871).

Comment: That's hysterical. 1980s children's programing was certainly at another level with its acting and production values.

Answer (score 5):

I wonder if you are recalling [*Science Ninja Team Gatchaman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_Ninja_Team_Gatchaman)/[*G-Force: Guardians of Space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-Force:_Guardians_of_Space)/[*Battle of the Planets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Planets) which is a 1970s or 1980s cartoon features a mother spaceship having a vehicle in the bow, which looks boxy when the car is approaching (as well as on the nacelles, and a dorsal docking center). While the bow does not use a ramp, some of the vehicles have ramp-like lifts.

You can see these in the opening video clip below:

Comment: I never watched any of those. I think the vehicle idea could have been Bionic Six